# how do I get the most recent 100 status of a user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can't seem to be able to find a parameters that allows me to get the most X recent status of a user.

Right now my graph API path looks like this:

```
/12345/status
```

and I can't see any parameters to be able to filter by the most recent and count. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this would do, but first you need permission for user_status. read this   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-profile-properties/

```
your_fb_id?fields=id,name,posts.limit(100)
```

you can try this code on the fb graph api explorer tool http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Answer (score 0):

[FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql) can be used to get the most recent status from a user's wall.

The following query will return the recent 100 status from a user excluding the status by themselves.

```
SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message 
FROM stream WHERE filter_key = 'nf' AND is_hidden = 0 AND actor_id != me() 
ORDER BY created_time DESC LIMIT 100
```

Here filter_key `'nf'` refers to news feed. You can find more details on the fields of the STREAM table in FQL from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream)

**Update:**

You can call any FQL queries using graph API , see [this blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/579/) from FB

Comment: I don't want FQL I want to use Graph API

Comment: @adit See my updates on the answers. you can query FQL using graph API itself.